# google youtube api 3.0: tailored search

Tags: youtube-api

How can I configure a search query so that the results are coming back with as much data as possible including

`like & dislike count`, `view count`, `uploaded on`, `category`, `embed` and so on etc...

When I used the following method

`$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
   'q' => $q,
   'maxResults' => $max_results,
));`

The results comes back limited to the following response;

```
Array
(
    [kind] => 
    [etag] => 
    [nextPageToken] => 
    [pageInfo] => Array
        (
            [totalResults] => 
            [resultsPerPage] => 
        )

    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [kind] => 
                    [etag] => 
                    [id] => Array
                        (
                            [kind] => 
                            [videoId] => 
                        )

                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 
                            [channelId] => 
                            [title] => 
                            [description] => 
                            [thumbnails] => Array

                            [channelTitle] => 
                            [liveBroadcastContent] => none
                        )

                )


        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'id' and 'snippet' parts are the only dimensions opened up to the search endpoint -- this is by design, as more data would be too expensive to return to a search query where most of the data wouldn't be used (I'm not saying you wouldn't use it, but by and large if more data were returned, most requests would be getting far more data than they need, making the whole system less efficient).

This is why the videos->list endpoint offers more dimensions ... searching is designed to find large chunks of videos, and then once you (or your users) filter down, you then do another call to get more detailed data based on the limited subset.

Comment: Thank you... so you are saying, instead of using `search->listSearch`, use `videos->list`. That should give me the details I need. Could you shed a little more light on when you say " you (or your users) filter down, you then do another call to get more detailed data based on the limited subset."

Comment: The way this is designed to work is that you should be providing the search results to your users in such a way that, if they need additional info about the video, you would then do a second call (so, for example, you show them a paginated list of search results, they click on one or more, and based on that info you do a call to videos->list to get the additional info). Some people complain about having to do multiple calls, but it's better than having lots of developers request all the detailed data for all the search results, and then none of it gets looked at by the user.